# Are equivalent group representations interchangeable in a trace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I'm learning group theory (and recapping math in general) and I'm missing one step in the following derivation.

Let $G$ be a finite group and

$X(g): V \rightarrow V$,

$Y(g): V \rightarrow V$

two irreducible representations of $G$ on some $V$.

We constructed an $A$ operator:
$$A:=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}  Y(g^{-1}) B  X(g) \tag{1}$$

for a $B:V \rightarrow V$. This $ A$ satisfy condition of Schur-lemma II.,  i.e. $Y^{-1}_{(g)} A X_{(g)} =  A$ (which is equivalent to   $Y_{(g^{-1})} A  X_{(g)} =  A)$ $\rightarrow  A =  0 $ or $\exists  A^{{-1}}$.

If $\exists  A^{{-1}}$, and the two representations are equivalent $ X \sim  Y$.

Then it is proven that $Tr(A)=Tr( B)$.

$$Tr( A) = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} Tr( Y_{(g^{-1})}B  X_{(g)}) = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}Tr( X_{(g^{-1})}B  X_{(g)}) = \\ = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}Tr( X^{-1}_{(g)}  X_{(g)}B) = \frac{1}{|G|} |G| Tr(B)=Tr(B) \tag{2} $$

Why can we change the two representation in the trace if they are equivalent?
It is known that $Tr(X) = Tr(CYC^{-1})= Tr(Y)$, but how can you prove that $Tr(YBX)=Tr(XBX)$ if $X \sim Y$. Or it's not a trace property at all?

Comment: I'd recommend adopting a notation that needs fewer marks to communicate the point. E.g., no hats, and call your two representations $D$ and $E$, rather than with superscript numbers in parentheses. Also, trace of an endomorphism is well-defined, but... summing over $g\in G$? Don't you want something more like trace of $D_g$ and/or trace of $E_g$, for each $g\in G$ (not summed)? Please advise...

Comment: Thanks for the advice about the notation, I changed them and  updated the derivation in the question also. This $A$ later used to derive the Schur orthogonality relations, which also contains a sum over ther group elements, so yes the summing is over $g$. However the magic happens inside the summation in the trace. Is it just a trace linear algebra property, or something else being used in (2)?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot replace an operator by a similar operator in a product and expect the trace of the product to be unchanged. For instance, it is well known that the trace of a product is unchanged under cyclic permutations of the arguments, but not under arbitrary permutations; therefore $\def\tr{\operatorname{Tr}}\tr(AB)=\tr(BA)$ always, and if at least one of $A,B$ is invertible then $AB$ and $BA$ are in fact similar, but it is nonetheless not generally the case that $\tr(ABC)$ and $\tr(BAC$) are the same (even when everything is invertible).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe this change in (2) is doable because this representation equivalence is much stronger than ordinary similarity: $X \sim Y$ holds for every $g \in G$.